# Elequent whereIn not working with array when array is too large

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an array like this:

`$array = ['1' , '2' ,'100'];`

and my query is :

`$query = Customer::whereIn('id', $array)->get();`

When the `$array` is too large (1500 items and above) , it's not work and return a null value.

Also I increased the `max_allowed_packet` in MySQL config. but problem not solved.

PHP v7.33 , laravel v7.19 , MySQL v 5.7

Comment: It's not your eloquent that is misbehaving, it is your DB driver that you are trying to kill. just change the way you are doing things (use a join or relations instead of a huge list of variables)

Comment: (>ლ) As said optimize your query, because everything has a limit, for example, C++ has around 100 `switch case` limit (anything more and gives nice compile error, and we are forced to use `else if`, did not yet reach else-if limit ;-) ).

Comment: You must clarify what you are trying to do. When you are dealing with large data you can always work in chunks Laravel query builder has the option:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects don't be fooled by the DB class you can do exactly the same with the Models.

Comment: I changed the logic and i used leftJoin in query builder and problem was solved.

Answer (score 16):

Ok, this took me 6 straight hours, but I managed to find a deep explanation of the problem !

The problem is in fact *not* with eloquent itself, but with the combinaison of both eloquent and the db to optimise queries.

Eloquent does prepare all queries with `PDO::prepare()`. In the case of a whereIn() query, the result is something like

```sql
PREPARE SELECT * FROM model WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, .....);
```

On his side, the db (mySQL, mariaDB) has a variable named `in_predicate_conversion_threshold` for specifically optimising the IN() clause. By default the value is `1000`, which mean the query will be converted to an optimised version implying subqueries.

So, binding more than 999 items in a IN clause can result in errors in which the DB will return 0 results without errors.

**Workaround 1**: Use a raw queries on laravel side.
**Workaround 2**: Use unprepared statements.
**Workaround 3**: Do chunk for selects or updates.
**Workaround 4**: Increase or remove the threshold for the IN optimisation (value of 0 = no optimisation).

For the last point, just execute `SET in_predicate_conversion_threshold = 0;` before your query, or set it up globally in the config file. (do not execute the query directly on the command line as this is session-based modifications)

Comment: thanks a lot for putting time to give this information to the community .

Comment: Thanks! This also explains why sometimes deeply nested/chained resource collections are returned as empty arrays, in case someone will stumble upon this.

Comment: Wow, i'd like to give a bounty for that, you really saved my day! Awesome information

Answer (score 8):

Use [whereIntegerInRaw](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orWhereIntegerInRaw) which makes sure the array is only integers,but skips prepare

```
Customer::whereIntegerInRaw('id', $array)->get();
```

Comment: Actually only this worked in my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to put an **UP** on this issue because we encounter it in our infrastructure as well.

The biggest problem isn't that Eloquent return null or empty, but the fact that **it doesn't produce error at all**, making it very hard to debug.

###### Some further test I made :

- Model::whereIn() is working with small list of ids
- Start returning empty array before 1500 entries
- Same query done with DB::select() works fine
- Same query done but with extracting query and binding from query builder works fine
- Same as above but with Model::hydrate() working fine

###### Conclusion :

- This is mainly a problem with Eloquent itself as it doesn't imply the underlying DB (or network limits)
- My version of doctrine: 2.13.8, laravel: v7.30.6. Cannot test with another versions right now, may be resolved in more recent versions
- Absent error reporting may be a bug or an incorrect configuration
- Workaround : raw query

Comment: You are so right that the silent failures are the WORST aspect of this.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem last month, I convert array to String then used **whereRaw**.

I think it is not suitable very large array

```
$str = null;
$arr = array_values($arr);
if (count($arr) > 0) {
    $str = 'user_code IN (\'' . implode('\',\'', $arr) .'\')';
}

$query = new Something();
if ($str != null) {
    $query = $query->whereRaw($trsUserCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about divide the query into chunks

```
  $chunk = 500;
  $query = Customer::query()
  for ($i = 0, $j = count($array); $i < $j; $i += $chunk) {
         $temp = array_slice($array, $i, $i + $chunk);
         $query->whereIn('id', $temp);   
   }
   $result = $query->get();
```