# weird results when using whereNotIn() in scope method in model in Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model called Lead. Within this model I have some local scopes defined. In one of those scopes I want to filter out all the phonenumbers which are present (after applying filters) in a certain table with the model Transaction.

```
public function scopeNotBlacklisted(Builder $query): void
{
    $blacklist = Transaction::where('finalized_at', '>=', now()->subDays(100)->toDateString())
        ->where('flow_id', '!=', '752')
        ->pluck('phonenumber')
        ->all();
    $query->whereNotIn('phonenumber', $blacklist);
}
```

So in this case the blacklist gives me all the phonenumbers of the transactions finalized in the last 100 days. Which are about +- 5000 phonenumbers. When I change the subDays to like 1 the blacklist only gives like 100 phonenumbers. This seems to be working fine.

Now when I actually call the scope, for some reason the result after filtering out the phonenumbers in the blacklist is not correct. It seems that it filters out more phonenumbers that there are in the blacklist array.

When I use subDays() between 1 and 51 it doesn't filter out anything. And when I use subDays() of 52 or more it filters out everything. I have checked it in the database and this should not be the result.

I am complete lost and have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Recently , I faced some problems with `whereNotIn` , I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71444367/10732390) very useful.

Adding `DB::statement('SET in_predicate_conversion_threshold=0');` before my query solved my problem.

it seems that there are some optimization applied on  `whereNotIn` and `whereIn` when the array of the IDs is more than 1000 ID.