# How to workaround limit of array size when using whereNotIn() in a local scope in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an array which I use to filter out the results of a certain query. There is a known issue where the query returns `null`, when the passed array in `whereNotIn()` or `whereIn()` exceeds a certain amount (I think like +- 1500 records). See: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71195829/elequent-wherein-not-working-with-array-when-array-is-too-large/71444367#71444367)

I have already read about some workarounds like using a raw queries or setting the `in_predicate_conversion_threshold` to 0. But I don't think the raw query is possible since it is a local scope and you build the query on top on an already existing query and I feel like setting the `in_predicate_conversion_threshold` to 0 is bad practice and I think it is only possible in a MariaDb database (and not in MySQL, which is what I am using). Also when doing this I get an error saying `in_predicate_conversion_threshold` is an Unknown system variable.

Now I think the best solution for this problem is to chunk the array in smaller pieces. But I have no idea how to achieve this using the query in a local scope.

```
public function scopeNotBlacklisted(Builder $query): void
{
    $blacklist = Transaction::where('finalized_at', '>=', now()->subDays(365)->toDateString())
        ->pluck('phonenumber')
        ->all();
    $query->whereNotIn('phonenumber', $blacklist);
}
```

Comment: why dont you left join the other table and filter the phone number like;

`LEFT JOIN transactions trans ON mainTable.phonenumber = trans.phonenumber AND trans.finalized_at >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)`

Then `WHERE trans.phonenumber IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using left join instead, then that return result if the join value is null

```
public function scopeNotBlacklisted(Builder $query): void {
    $query->leftJoin('transactions as tr', function ( $join ) {
        $join->on('YOUR_WHATEVER_TABLE_HERE.phonenumber', '=', 'tr.phonenumber')
            ->where('tr.finalized_at', '>=', now()->subDays(365)->toDateString());
    })->whereNull('tr.phonenumber');
}
```

**EDIT**- another method you could try without using left join but do raw query instead using `>whereNotExists`

```
public function scopeNotBlacklisted(Builder $query): void {
    $query->whereNotExists(function ($sub) {
        $sub->selectRaw('1')
        ->from('transactions as tr')
        ->where('tr.finalized_at', '>=', now()->subDays(365)->toDateString())
        ->whereColumn('tr.phonenumber', '=', 'YOUR_MAIN_TABLE.phonenumber');
    });
}
```

Comment: I get an Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous. Probably because in other scopes I use order by  'created_at'

Comment: does your `transactions` table have `created_at` column? joining the table will combine their columns, so if you have the same column names, you need to properly specify which table column you are referring in each clause,  probably should have to define the table in your order clause like `->orderDesc('maintable.created_at')`

Comment: you can post your actual query the uses that scope as well as the two table structure you are doing the query.

Comment: I solved it by putting the table name before all overlapping column names in all the scopes.. seems to be working fine now!

Comment: I also edited my answer, adding another method without using left join, but rather use `whereNotExists`

Comment: could you delete the first part of your answer.. i later concluded that that didnt work since the phonenumber columns where all null in the result of the query.. the edited answer did work btw!

Comment: You can also just use  `whereNotIn` with a subquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_chunk in your `scope` as below.

```
public function scopeNotBlacklisted(Builder $query): void
{
    $blacklist = Transaction::where('finalized_at', '>=', now()->subDays(365)->toDateString())
        ->pluck('phonenumber')
        ->all();

    $chunkedBlacklist = array_chunk($blacklist, 500); // you can adjust count here.

   
    collect($chunkedBlacklist)->each(function ($chunk) use ($query) {
        $query->unless(empty($chunk), function ($query) use ($chunk) {
            $query->whereNotIn('phonenumber', $chunk);
        });
    });
}
```

Another option to handle large sets of data for `whereIn` or `whereNotIn` clauses is to use temporary tables.

Comment: Unfortunately chunking the array gave me the same result :(